# Updating a list within a list<class>

Tags: c#, list

Since having a `list<list<>>` is bad practice, i have created a class containing 2 lists:

```
public class TouchSet
{
    public List<DateTime> timeList = new List<DateTime>(ammountOfXValues);
    public List<int> touchList = new List<int>(ammountOfXValues);
}
```

Then i have a function that is used to initialize the entire thing so i can use it further down the road:

```
public void initializeTouchDataListObject()
{
    touchSetList = new List<DataStructure.TouchSet>(DataStructure.maxButtonsActive);

    List<int> tempTouchList = new List<int>();
    List<DateTime> tempTimeList = new List<DateTime>();
    for (int a = 0; a < DataStructure.maxButtonsActive; a++)
    {
        DataStructure.TouchSet tempTouchSet = new DataStructure.TouchSet();
        tempTouchSet.timeList = tempTimeList;
        tempTouchSet.touchList = tempTouchList;
        touchSetList.Add(tempTouchSet);
    }
}
```

This is the loop where i add values to the list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataStructure.maxButtonsActive; i++)
{
    if(touchSetList[i].timeList.Count == DataStructure.ammountOfXValues)
    {
        //RemoveAt removes at the given index within a list
        touchSetList[i].timeList.RemoveAt(0);
        touchSetList[i].touchList.RemoveAt(0);
        //add
        touchSetList[i].timeList.Add(DateTime.Now);
        touchSetList[i].touchList.Add(temp);
    }
    else if(touchSetList[i].timeList.Count < DataStructure.ammountOfXValues)
    {
        //add
        touchSetList[i].timeList.Add(DateTime.Now);
        touchSetList[i].touchList.Add(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        int overLength = touchSetList[i].timeList.Count - DataStructure.ammountOfXValues;
        //remove
        touchSetList[i].timeList.RemoveRange(0, overLength + 1);
        touchSetList[i].touchList.RemoveRange(0, overLength + 1);

        //add
        touchSetList[i].timeList.Add(DateTime.Now);
        touchSetList[i].touchList.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is, that within a single pass through the for loop , it adds temp to every touchList not just the touchList of `touchSetList[i]`.

For example after adding temp to `touchSetList[i].touchList` every other `touchList` also contains temp, not just the one where the index i applies to the class within the list.

I'm not sure why the List is behaving this way, and why it adds the value to every list not just the one with the corresponding index. I was under the impression that you can use an index to access a single item within a list. Any pointers or advice is appreciated.

Comment: Why are nested lists bad practice?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: because OP's class is much better to read and to maintain? Try to add more properties to a `List<List<object>>`. Since `DateTime` and `int` are also different types you always have to cast them according to their index in the inner list. You could use a `List<List<Tuple<DateTime,int>>>`, but that's not much better.

Comment: In his case, yes, but in his case I'd redesign anyway. Just writing an answer suggesting this.

Comment: @MatthewWatson it is initialized within the for loop. i have removed it for the demonstration tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void initializeTouchDataListObject()
{
    touchSetList = new List<DataStructure.TouchSet>(DataStructure.maxButtonsActive);

    for (int a = 0; a < DataStructure.maxButtonsActive; a++)
    {
        List<DateTime> tempTimeList = new List<DateTime>();
        List<int> tempTouchList = new List<int>();
        DataStructure.TouchSet tempTouchSet = new DataStructure.TouchSet();
        tempTouchSet.timeList = tempTimeList;
        tempTouchSet.touchList = tempTouchList;
        touchSetList.Add(tempTouchSet);
    }
}
```

You don't create a new tempTimeList and tempTouchList for every new tempTouchSet, so they all get passed pointers to THE SAME list.

Do the initialization for tempTimeList and tempTouchList within your loop and you get a new one for every tempTouchSet.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I'd redesign the entire thing. What I read from your code is that you want to store the timestamp of a touch event together with some information about the touch event.

So I'd design a class that contains all that data:

```
public class TouchInfo
{
    public DateTime touchTime;
    public int touchEvent;
}
```

Then you can easily store one list of  touch events, instead having to keep two lists in sync.

```
List<TouchInfo> touchEvents = new List<TouchInfo>();

public void initializeTouchDataListObject()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < DataStructure.maxButtonsActive; a++)
    {
        touchEvents.add(new TouchInfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `initializeTouchDataListObject()` method, you create `tempTouchList` and `tempTimeList`. Then, for EVERY `TouchSet`, you add these lists as their `timeList` and `touchList`. The problem here is that the two created lists are passed by REFERENCE, meaning that every single `TouchSet` has a reference to the two exact same lists. They all share the same lists and thus lists are changed for every `TouchSet` in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 conditions. Add(temp) is in all 3.

```css
1) a < b
2) a = b
3) a > c
​
```